# Uninstall an Windows Update with a Script

Tags: script, windows-update, uninstall, internet-explorer-9

I created a series of images for various types of hardware based on a user specs, but they have now decided that they no longer want IE9 but IE8 instead due to web apps.

I can roll back the update on the images but we have already deployed on around 200 desktops and I now need to figure out a way to uninstall it using an automated method.

Its basically the IE9 Windows update that needs to be removed.

Any suggestions how i can accomplish it with a script? I did the usual googling but only found one vaguely documented vb script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the client machines are Windows 7. Since IE 9 is treated as a feature in Windows 7, you can uninstall it, which will automatically revert IE to IE 8.

To add/remove Windows features, you can use the built in [DISM.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd490958.aspx). A good guide to use DISM.exe to install/uninstall Windows Features can be found [here](http://itcookbook.net/blog/Enabling-and-disabling-Windows-7-components-from-commandline). On my Windows 7 x64 machine, the name of IE feature is:

[image]

> DISM can be used to service Windows Vista with Service Pack 1 (SP1)
>   and Windows Server 2008. When used with Windows 7 and Windows Server
>   2008 R2, you get the added functionality.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I have not used the DISM tools for updates yet. Will do some reading on this. Not sure Why I have been voted down though.